# enviar una variable por post a una funcion en c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

buenos días.

puede que para muchos esta sea una pregunta de nivel básico pero necesito ayuda, estoy viendo un video (porque se me han ido olvidando hartas cosas de asp.net) y llegué a este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLbexJoTOP8&list=PL0kIvpOlieSNWR3YPSjh9P2p43SFnNBlB&index=11) en donde se explica como pasar variables ya sea por GET o POST desde un formulario a una función.

Mi formulario es este:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="info_front">
                <form action="id_front" method="POST">
                    <input id="c_front" type="text" value="" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Siguiente </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En el action le indico la función a la que tiene que enviar la información. Por el lado del controlador tengo esto:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult id_front(string id_front)
        {
            idd_front = id_front;
            return RedirectToAction("CedulaTrasera");
        }
```

Si escribo alguna cosa y doy click en el botón del formulario y pongo un punto de interrupción en mi función, estoy llegando bien pero no estoy recibiendo el dato del input.
No sé si estoy mandando mal lo que necesito o me falta algo.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar con esto.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Y si lo especificas en la ruta o en el startup? Mira este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY te será de ayuda :D //para que recibas la variable, coloca "id" en lugar de "id_front"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por como estas llamando a tu input, en tu metodo dejalo de la siguiente forma

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult id_front(string c_front)
    {
        idd_front = c_front;
        return RedirectToAction("CedulaTrasera");
    }
```

Con eso deberia quedar

Comment: me sigue llegando como null la variable... no podría ser otra cosa??

Comment: <input id="c_front" type="text" value="" /> usa la etiqueta name para que quede asi <input id="c_front" type="text" name="c_front" value="" />

Comment: eso era, muchas gracias

Comment: de nada para eso estamos aqui saludos